# Virtual device running in Genymotion periodically goes offline in ADB

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I have an Android device (with Lollipop image, if important) running in Genymotion 2.4 and connect to it via ADB (version 1.0.32) from another developer PC with Eclipse in local network without connectivity problems. All is fine except for periodical drops of ADB connection (other protocols keep working fine), that is ADB loses the device, and when I try to reconnect it says that device is offline. From my experience, this offline status does basically mean that the receiving end (the device) still thinks it's connected and declines new connection. The only method I know to remedy this problem is to restart the device and then ADB connects to it as expected.

If someone is interested, ADB is not running on the remote host machine with Genymotion - otherwise the remove connections from other PCs would be impossible.

The question: how can I refresh "softly" the virtual device to accept new ADB connection without restarting entire device?

P.S. If I leave the "offline" device for its own for some time (quite a long time, for example, for an hour) it seems refreshes its state without external interaction, so ADB is again able to properly connect to and device is reported as "online". But, it makes no sense to wait so long for this to happen. This is just a new piece of information for consideration.

Comment: yes issue with my genymotion too. The emulator gets offline frequently , specially when my PC goes to sleep. I always need to restart the emulator. There must be a better solution

Answer (score 19):

This may not work for you, but has worked for me in the situation where my device simply goes ADB offline. One of the comments on your question mentions that their emulator typically goes offline when their device sleeps. Mine does the same and also goes offline after long periods of inactivity, despite not actually sleeping. Anyway, my fix is plain and simple:

In terminal, navigate to where you have the SDK installed. Then, navigate to the directory platform-tools within your SDK, and issue the following command:

```
adb kill-server
```

After that finishes, type this one:

```
adb devices
```

That almost always fixes my problem, and I hope it fixes yours as well. Let me know how that works for you.

Comment: Worked for me, although I had to run `adb devices` twice in my machine. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Beats closing down my emulator and restarting genymotion.

Comment: @chetan I need a little more information from you to make any kind of intelligent response. Have you seen the list of devices previously? Have you allowed the device in question with your computer? Is the device currently connected and powered on? I'd love to help but unfortunately need more info.

Comment: 1.Yes when I connect actual device, No when I run virtual device. 2.Yes 3. yes the virtual device is connected and powered on.

Answer (score 1):

If you use **MacOS Sierra** - there is a known bug in it.

***28.11.2016*** There is no workaround yet except restarting adb which is suggested in @lustig answer.

- Google gonna fix it in Android Studio 2.3. Issues to track [82425](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82425), [216214](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216214)
- There is no info about will Apple fix it on their side or not.

Comment: No. My both PCs were running Windows. From your answer it's not clear if it's fixed in specific version of ADB. If yes, then which version? Mentioning Android Studio is not enough.

Comment: @Stan updated my answer, however seems it's not related to Windows. Leaving it for MacOS users.

Comment: Yes, I have this issue on MacOS Sierra and @lustig answer is not working for me.