# Bring Genymotion emulator device to online mode without restarting

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, genymotion

I looked online but I could not find an answer to this question. Is there a way to **make Genymotion emulator go online after it has become offline** without restarting the Genymotion AVD?

Comment: What do you mean by going online and offline?

Comment: When my laptop goes on sleep mode or is unused for a certain period of time, the Genymotion virtual device goes offline as well. Then, my IDE (Android studio for my case) cannot seems to display it in the list of deployment target devices. My question is, instead of restarting the virtual device by killing it from the "close button" or from the VirtualBox, can someone reconnect that device without having to kill it?

Comment: This one works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35304957/1307877